# Change the images URI values within an array

Tags: uri, services

In a custom module of services 3.x Drupal 7 that queries the database, I get the values of the URIs of some images within some nodes.

This is part of module:

```
$res = db_query("SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS title, body.body_value AS body, fm.uri AS uri    
FROM {node} node 
INNER JOIN {field_data_body body} ON body.entity_id = node.nid 
INNER JOIN {field_data_field_header_image header} ON header.entity_id = node.nid 
INNER JOIN {file_managed fm} ON fm.fid = header.field_header_image_fid 
WHERE ((node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN ('tiendas')))
ORDER BY nid DESC");

foreach ($res as $cupon) {
$resultados[] = $cupon;
}
return resultados;
```

And this the json returned by the web services:

```
[
 {
  "nid": "6",
  "title": "Negron Beach Bar",
  "body": "<p>Este es el descuento de Negron</p>\r\n",
  "uri": "public://negron.png"
 },
 {
  "nid": "5",
  "title": "PizaPuck",
  "body": "<p>Este es el descuento de PizaPuck</p>\r\n",
  "uri": "public://pizapuck.png"
 }
]
```

But I need the full url. Not the URI. The json should look like this:

```
 {
  "nid": "5",
  "title": "PizaPuck",
  "body": "<p>Este es el descuento de PizaPuck</p>\r\n",
  "uri": "http://example.com/site/default/files/pizapuck.png"
 }
```

If I use this from below I get the url I need (in $path), but I have to put the URI value by hand:

```
$uri = "public://pizapuck.png"; //by hand
if ($wrapper = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri($uri)) {
$path = $wrapper->getExternalUrl();
}
```

How can I do to replace every URI value inside the array? I need to extract every value of URI, replace it with the path value, and put it back into the array? I understand this is basic and simple, but my knowledge of php, pdo, ppo and mysql are quite poor. Any help on this matter thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have success with

```
file_create_url("public://pizapuck.png");
```

so

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < count($resultados); $i++){
  $resultados[$i]['uri'] = file_create_url($resultados[$i]['uri']);
}
```

would loop through your results and change them. (untested code typed directly in here).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The url that I get is correct if I use file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri($uri)) But the problem is modify the array. I try your solution with this response : Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in eval()

Comment: Uff, I'm not a programmer. My knowledge is very poor, but finally trying I have changed this: $resultados[$i]['uri'] =

For this other: $resultados[$i]->uri =

And the error was solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally after reading and reading and trying everything, this is what worked for me:

I have created a function that replaces the URI with the complete URL.

`function uritourl($uri){
  if ($wrapper = file_stream_wrapper_get_instance_by_uri($uri)) {
    $path = $wrapper->getExternalUrl();
    return $path;
  }
}`

And inside a for I have called it to replace every value in the array.

`foreach ($res as $cupon) {
   $resultados[] = $cupon;
  }
for ( $i = 0; $i < count($resultados); $i++){
  $uri = $resultados[$i]->uri;
  $resultados[$i]->uri = uritourl($uri);
}
return $resultados;`

There will be more elegant, safe or quick ways to do it, but my knowledge is very scarce. I hope this helps someone.